# What's the difference between the ST-LINK/V2 and STX-RLINK programmers?

Tags: jtag

Do both support full on debugging with the ability to set breakpoints etc?

[ST-LINK/V2](http://www.st.com/internet/evalboard/product/251168.jsp)

[STX-RLINK](http://www.st.com/internet/evalboard/product/122903.jsp)

Comment: I would ask your ST distributor's FAE.

Comment: ST-Link/V2 is an ST product that will set you back about $10...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both should be able to debug and add breakpoint. I believe STX-Rlink works with the Raisonance compiler only which is based on the GNU C compiler. The free compiler is limited to a few breakpoints. For the ST-link, you can get that working for popular ARM compilers like Keil and IAR. I use Keil quite often with ST-Link. The evaluation version of the Keil and IAR is code limited to 16k I believe.